# Why isn't emacs displaying my theme?

Tags: themes

Issuing `M-x load-theme` gives me the option `solarized`. However, issuing `solarized` gives the message `Undefined Custom theme solarized`.

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Did you try `M-x enable-theme`?

Comment: @TomRegner Issuing `M-x enable-theme` does not give `solarized` as a possible completion.

Comment: Even after it's loaded (with `M-x load-theme`)?

Comment: @TomRegner But my problem is that I can't load the theme...

Comment: Ah - english is not my first language, misread your post -- sorry for the noise.

Comment: Can you successfully load it with `load-library`?

Comment: Did you install the theme through a package manager like MELPA?

Answer (score 1):

When you write a theme, you need to make sure everything is named correctly:

- Your theme file must end with the postfix (or should I say suffix?) `-theme`
- Your `deftheme`, `provide-theme`, and `custom-theme-set-faces` must **not** have the theme postfix `-theme`

I'm not sure if all of those are really needed, but I always do like this so I don't have this undefined error.

Oh, and don't forget to add your theme dir to the `custom-theme-load-path` list